# php increment a value

Tags: php, while-loop

I have set to constants, a start year and an end year,
so i have built a while loop on the condition that

```
if the start year is < than the current year increment until true.
```

the problem i have is that instead of it going up like this:

```
1999,2000,2001,2002,2003,2004
```

it goes like:

```
1999,2001,2003,2005,2007,2009
```

Here is my code:

```
function yearCount()
{
  $yearBegin = START_YEAR;
  $yearCurrent = CURRENT_YEAR;
  while($yearBegin < $yearCurrent){
    echo "<option value=\"".$yearBegin++."\">".$yearBegin++."</option>";
  }
}
```

any ideas would be highly appreciated.

Comment: There is something wrong in your code.

Comment: We need of the code to find the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are incrementing the value twice:

```
echo "<option value=\"".$yearBegin++."\">".$yearBegin++."</option>";
```

Each `$yearBegin++` increments it by one.

Use a for loop instead:

```
for ($yearBegin = START_YEAR; $yearBegin < CURRENT_YEAR; $yearBegin++)
{
  echo "<option value=\"".$yearBegin."\">".$yearBegin."</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Using a for loop is usually the way to do this,

```
for($year=START_YEAR;$year<=CURRENT_YEAR;$year++)
{
    //User the $year here
}
```

your problem with the code is that your calling `$yearBegin++` 2 times within the while loop, causing it to increment twice.

using the for loop is much cleaner then as incrementing is done within the expression for you

Answer (score 4):

```
function yearCount()
{
  $yearBegin = START_YEAR;
  $yearCurrent = CURRENT_YEAR;
  while($yearBegin < $yearCurrent){
    $this_year = $yearBegin++;
    echo "<option value=\"".$this_year."\">".$this_year."</option>";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use only one time `++` , increment

```
echo "<option value=\"".$yearBegin."\">".$yearBegin++."</option>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You increment $yearBegin twice, one time in the value part, one time in the display part ...

You need to change it so it only increments once

Answer (score 0):

You increment it twice, once setting it as a value, and the second time displaying it in option tag